# Doubts about Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I'm developing my first win app and I have some doubts about setup project.

I'm using LinqToSql with a local database file. I know that must add this database to the setup project.

But, if I install this app in another machine, this machine must have sql server express installed to run my app?

I've user 4.0 framework. Do I have to add the 4.0 installer to the setup project as well?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs SQL Server Express and .NET Framework to run, you can add them as prerequisites to your installer. Visual Studio setup project should have them in the predefined prerequisites list.

Comment: If your application is using SQL databases, most likely you need an SQL server. Also, the LinqToSQL documentation indicates that you should use it with SQL Server Express. You can always test this on a clean machine (see if it works without SQL Server).